# Regex matching newline character by default in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to check whether the given string input is a number of six digits.

Valid:

```
* 123456
* 098765
```

Invalid:

```
* 123
* 12345a
* as3445
* /n123456
* 123456\n
```

My Python code:

```
bool(re.match("^[0-9]{6}$",string))
```

but this also matches `"123456\n"`.

Why it is matching newline character and how to restrict this match?

Comment: You could use `^[0-9]{6}\Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in comment,  `\Z` : *asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string*

```
values = ["123456", "098765", "Invalid:", "123", "12345a", "as3445", "/n123456", "123456\n"]
for v in values:
    print("{:10s} {}".format(v, bool(re.match("^[0-9]{6}\Z", v))))


123456     True
098765     True
Invalid:   False
123        False
12345a     False
as3445     False
/n123456   False
123456
    False
```